# Need help making build.xml for Ant build of my Java project

Tags: java, ant, build.xml

I have a project set up like this;

```
Project
    -src
        -com
            -top
                -classes
                    Class_3.java
                    Class_4.java
                -utils
                    Class_5.java
                    Class_6.java
                Class_1.java
                Class_2.java
    -data
        various files
    -libs
        lib_1.jar
        lib_2.jar
        lib_3.jar
        lib_4.jar
    build.xml
```

class_1.java contains the main class, libs contains external dependencies, data contains various images, text files etc...

I have been trying to write an Ant build file to make a distributable JAR file but am having difficultied pulling in all the required libraries etc...

This is where I am up to.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Project" default="jar">

    <property name="libsSrc" value="libs"/>
    <property name="build" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes" value="build/classes"/>
    <property name="jar" value="build/jar"/>
    <property name="libs" value="build/libs"/>

    <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="${libsSrc}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <target name="clean" description="remove intermediate files">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="compile the Java source code to class files">
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
        <javac srcdir="." destdir="${classes}" classpathref="classpath">
            <compilerarg line="-encoding utf-8"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="create a Jar file for the application">
        <mkdir dir="${jar}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar}/App.jar">
            <fileset dir="${classes}" includes="**/*.class"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.top.Class_1"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

This doesn't work currently.

It compiles with no errors but doesn't include the required dependencies and the JAR cannot find the main class. How can I fix it?

Comment: if you edit is the answer to your question, then please post it as an answer (which you can accept later). But actually there is no real question and you may want to delete this alltogether.

Comment: Apologies, all comments addressed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Rutherford" default="jar">

    <property name="libsSrc" value="libs"/>
    <property name="build" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes" value="build/classes"/>
    <property name="jar" value="build/jar"/>
    <property name="libs" value="build/libs"/>

    <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="${libsSrc}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <pathconvert property="mf.classpath" pathsep=" ">
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <mapper>
                    <chainedmapper>
                            <flattenmapper/>
                            <globmapper from="*.jar" to="lib/*.jar"/>
                    </chainedmapper>
            </mapper>
    </pathconvert>

    <target name="clean" description="remove intermediate files">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="compile the Java source code to class files">
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
        <javac srcdir="." destdir="${classes}" classpathref="classpath">
            <compilerarg line="-encoding utf-8"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="create a Jar file for the application">
        <mkdir dir="${jar}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar}/App.jar">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${libsSrc}" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${classes}" includes="**/*.class"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="com.top.Class_1"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${mf.classpath}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

Seems to do the trick but the line;

```
<compilerarg line="-encoding utf-8"/>
```

seems to do nothing, I have a few text files containing UTF-8 encoded characters that are read into strings and displayed that are not showing properly; dσ/dΩ shows as dÃ/d©. I will ask that in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706183/java-application-reads-utf-8-encoded-text-files-but-after-ant-build-the-characte) though.

Comment: I didnt get your question, are you able to run your ant tasks??? what happens when you run "ant compile"??

Comment: I have actually solved all the problems associated with this question, I have edited (and may edit some more) the original question to make it a bit more clear.