# Java application reads UTF-8 encoded text files but after ant build the characters are not as expected

Tags: java, ant, build, build.xml

I have a Java project that reads UTF-8 encoded .txt files in order to construct strings that are displayed. Running in Eclipse the files are read and displayed as expected but after my ant build the characters are not coming out as they should.

Here is my build.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Rutherford" default="jar">

    <property name="libsSrc" value="libs"/>
    <property name="build" value="build"/>
    <property name="classes" value="build/classes"/>
    <property name="jar" value="build/jar"/>
    <property name="libs" value="build/libs"/>

    <path id="classpath">
            <fileset dir="${libsSrc}" includes="*.jar"/>
    </path>

    <pathconvert property="mf.classpath" pathsep=" ">
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <mapper>
                    <chainedmapper>
                            <flattenmapper/>
                            <globmapper from="*.jar" to="lib/*.jar"/>
                    </chainedmapper>
            </mapper>
    </pathconvert>

    <target name="clean" description="remove intermediate files">
        <delete dir="build"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" description="compile the Java source code to class files">
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
        <javac srcdir="." destdir="${classes}" classpathref="classpath">
            <compilerarg line="-encoding utf-8"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="jar" depends="compile" description="create a Jar file for the application">
        <mkdir dir="${jar}"/>
        <jar destfile="${jar}/App.jar">
            <zipgroupfileset dir="${libsSrc}" includes="*.jar"/>
            <fileset dir="${classes}" includes="**/*.class"/>
            <manifest>
                <attribute name="Main-Class" value="nat.rutherford.DesktopStarter"/>
                <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${mf.classpath}"/>
            </manifest>
        </jar>
    </target>

</project>
```

I tried to compile with UTF-8 character encoding using

```
<compilerarg line="-encoding utf-8"/>
```

but obviously this is not enough, what do I need to modify to get this to work?

Thanks

**Edit 1**

I read the .txt files in with.

```
public String fileToString(String file) {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(Gdx.files.internal(file).read());
    return new Scanner(in).useDelimiter("\\A").next();
}
```

which returns a string to a String variable, then I simply take this string and pass it to an [object](http://libgdx.l33tlabs.org/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/Label.html)

It works ok when compiling and running within eclipse.

**Edit 2**

This is the fix

```
public String fileToString(String file) {
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(Gdx.files.internal(file).read());
    return new Scanner(in, "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A").next();
}
```

Simple when you know where to look! lol Thanks!

Comment: So I presume you are talking about resource files here, which should be copied by ant to the folder containing the compiled classes?

Comment: @owlstead Yes they are resource files and no they are not currently copied in to the folder containing the compiled classes I currently just stick them in manually alongside the JAR. I'm not very good with Ant. Do you think that if I copy them in it'll work? I had a suspicion that this might be the case but I wasn't sure how to accomplish it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per [The documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html), use `encoding='utf-8'` instead of `compiler-arg`.

However ... I suspect that your problem is runtime, not compile time. Do you create `OutputStreamWriter` objects without passing an encoding? Or pass interesting chars to `System.out.println`? Or correspondingly `InputStreamReader` or `Scanner`? The fix in this case would be to add `-Dfile.encoding=utf-8` to the command line.

Comment: using <javac><encoding>utf-8</encoding></javac> gives a compile error, **javac doesn't support the nested "encoding" element.** placing the encoding parameter within the javac tag allows it to compile. However this has not solved the problem, my characters are still displaying incorrectly.

Comment: please see my **edit 1** for what I do with the .txt files (I'm using the libGDX library but I don't believe that that has a baring on this problem).

Comment: You were right, it was a runtime issue. I simply changed my Scanner as seen in **Edit 2**